# Как напечать +3 пробельных символа к ширине поля?

Tags: c

Здравствуйте!

В задании просят вывести имя, в поле шириной на три символа превышающим длину имени. Язык программирования - си.

Не могу понять, как это реализовать.

Пробовал:

```
printf("%",strlen(name)+3, "s\n", name);
```

Делал ещё разные способы - не прокатило. Объясните пожалуйста, как реализовать.

Спасибо!

**PS** Использовать можно только printf, scanf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ширина поля вывода устанавливается астериском. Т.е. формально можно написать так
    printf("%*s",strlen(name)+3, name);

Значение name тут будет выведено с выравниванием вправо. Выровнять по левой границе можно так:
    printf("%-*s",strlen(name)+3, name);

Comment: То есть на место звездочки появится нужное мне число?   
А почему это происходит, я просто не пойму?

Comment: Потому что так работает форматный вывод printf. Читайте спецификацию. Число не появится, зато printf, встретив астерикс в спецификаторе ширины поля, поймет что следующий аргумент в списке - это размер и считает его из стека

Answer (score 5):

Просто три пробела сзади вывести в форматной строке нельзя?

```
printf("%s   \n", name)
```

Comment: Так не интересно :).